# How to reproduce e:force:navigateTo in visualforce

Tags: visualforce, lightning

We need to have a visualforce page which can be used in classic or lightning, however when in Lightning the links should behave like Lightning Navigation.

Could we potentially pass in a function when creating the component, and this function would behave differently in Visualforce context and Lightning context ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"when in classic the links should behave like Lightning Navigation" - This does not make sense. Nothing like Lightning Navigation is available in Classic.

In any case, in Lightning you can use from Visualforce `sforce.one.navigateToURL`, `sforce.one.navigateToSObject` to prompt the `one.app` container to navigate away. So something like (excuse any errors):

```
<a href="/blah" onclick="navHandler(event)">My link is here</a>

<script>
var navHandler = function(event){
    if (window.sforce && sforce.one) {
        sforce.one.navigateToURL('/lightning/blah/blah/blah');
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
</script>
```

So this way the link behaves as a link in Classic but uses navigation in Lightning. Sometimes I get fancier and make sure to avoid intervening in middle-clicks or Ctrl/Shift-clicks so that the user does not lose their expected "open in new tab/window" behaviours.

Comment: Outstanding, thank you. You also understood that my question was wrong, I have corrected